Formula for finding the force between a U-shaped Electromagnet and a ferromagnetic plate
I am trying to find an accurate formula for the force generated between a U-shaped electromagnet with its winding on each tooth, and a ferromagnetic plate 20mm away form its surface. The electromagnet core is made from laminated electrical steel and the ferromagnetic plate(10mm thick) is made from AISI 1020.
I am currently working on a project that requires a control system for the levitation of the situation mentioned above. I have gotten results in my simulation, but want to verify it with a mathematical model, that will later be used to finalize gain values for my control system.

Winding specification on each tooth:
Turns = 300
Wire cross section dimension = 2.5mm*1mm
Height, width, length of tooth = 30mm, 20mm, 200mm
Height, width of total coil= 30mm, 25mm
Current = 10A
